# How to Group sequence elements above threshold?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq, grouping

I am looking for an algorithm for grouping element in a sequence.
Example:
I have the follwing list:

```
1 2 3 4 5 11 11 12 13 3 5 6 11 22 12 24 5 6 22 33
```

I want to find all the sequences with more than 3 items with values greater than 10.

So I will get:

```
11 11 12 13

11 22 12 24
```

Can I do it with a Linq query?  what is the best way to do it?

Comment: `GroupBy` - im sure if you entered your question into a search engine you could have found this

**Edit** [I was right](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=group+elements+in+a+sequence+c%23&oq=group+elements+in+a+sequence+c%23&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.5480j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Sayse: Try to answer this question with `GroupBy`.  I don't think you'll be able to.

Comment: @Andomar - I realised that I misread the question a bit - I thought he was after this - http://pastebin.com/MbT3tcQx

Answer (score 4):

Here's my LinqPad version which works. Not sure if you want this :-)

```
void Main() {
    var data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 11, 12, 13, 3, 5, 6, 11, 22, 12, 24, 5, 6, 22, 33 };
    var t = 10;  // threshold
    var m = 3;   // max-in-group
    var result = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length)
        .Select(x => new { 
            // the sequence
            d = data.Skip(x).TakeWhile(y => y > t).ToList(),
            // an indicator is the previous was empty
            // we need this to remove unwanted sequences
            p = x > 0 ? !data.Skip(x - 1).TakeWhile(y => y > t).Any() : true 
        })
        .Where(x => x.p && x.d.Count() > m)
        .Select(x => x.d);
    // LinqPad method to show the value of variable result.
    result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Where/What is the result.Dump() method?

Comment: @rantri: It's an extension method from LINQPad. It essentially outputs the data in that variable to the screen. It is not relevant to the algorithm.

Comment: Single letter variable names, really inefficient algorithm.  @rantri: The dump methond is available when you run [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) in C# Program mode.

Comment: @Andomar The OP doesn't state anything about the volumes of data. For the sample shown this will perform just fine. I agree that this won't be the best solution for large volumes.

Comment: @Maarten: Just a thought for future answers: If the OP seems to be a LINQ novice, it is a good idea to note if the algorithm is inefficient. A lot of "bad press" about LINQ comes from such nested algorithms, because people don't understand the big O behind it.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is not your best option here, because you need information about preceeding and following items to get the result. A simple loop will be the easiest way to implement it:

```
var result = new List<List<int>>();

var sequence = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in original)
{
    if(item <= 10)
    {
        if(sequence.Count > 3)
            result.Add(sequence);
        sequence = new List<int>();
    }
    else
        sequence.Add(item);
}

if(sequence.Count > 3)
    result.Add(sequence);
```

Comment: Have you tested your answer before downvoting others? Your result contains four sequences with items lower that 10, which isn't quite correct.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Thanks. Corrected. In fact, I didn't test it, I was busy arguing with those other guys about the legit downvotes.

Comment: -1: This doesn't work at all. 4 results which are all incorrect.

Comment: @Daniel, see? You will be asked the same questions as well! Did you test it before posting your answer?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, do not be over confident!

Comment: Don't flame, we're all programmers. Peace !

Comment: @David: I am not. With your ridiculous discussion you diverted my attention away from my own answer. Furthermore, the error in the answer was very minor. It wasn't entirely incorrect as the others. Finally, I corrected the answer in the meantime. The other answers are still incorrect.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, do not find an excute, I never force you to follow up. If you feel distracted, stop writing and do whatever you like, immediately!

Comment: @David: I found it more important to refute your comment than to test my answer. This is not an excuse, just an explanation.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, interesting. See your below comments, you said, you can still see my deleted answer, are you explaining? You just find an excuse, so that justifying you do not need even have a look! I don't understand your logic! As I said, you might be more experienced, I have no doubt on that, but please be patient to have a look at other's answer before you do that! Is this harsh and unacceptable to you?

Comment: @David: I have asked you this already at least twice, and I am going to continue asking it: What am I supposed to wait for? You ask me to be patient. This implies I am impatient which is not the case. A wrong answer doesn't get automatically correct over time. The downvote along with the comment encourages the answerer to correct the answer - or delete it if he isn't able to correct it. And I am really tired of you assuming I didn't look at the answers I downvoted. I looked at every single one of them.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, using your own logic and I have been asking you the same question. Did you finished looking at other's answer before you downvote? I will keep questioning you as well. Pleas answer first.

Comment: BTW: The downvotes on my answer are not justified. It fullfils the requirements of the OP. A downvote out of spite / vengeance is just poor. Think about it.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, your logic is "once I feel incorrect, it is the case"? I don't think it is a good way, :) be cautious to downvote! As I said, reading it through, and down vote, this will do you no harm!

Comment: @David: Please read the comment you just answered. It explicitly stated that I looked at every answer I downvoted. Can't you understand that? Or do you read only the parts you like?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I did not test your code, and I did not downvote either. what we have been discussing is, do one and should one be patient enough to have a full look before a post is downvoted? I cannot understand your logic, you keep asking me, and said due to this, you are distracted, I feel ridiculous, I never ask you to respond to my comment, you can do it, but do not complain that you are distracted.

Comment: @David: I **did** read them, I took into account all *relevant* information, why can't you understand that?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, here is the fact, to read it through my answer, you need scroll it, at least 3 seconds, but after posting my answer, less than 1 second, it is downvoted. I don't believe a person, unless you are the god, can read it, digest it, and respond within 0.5 second, if you can explain this, I am happy to apologize to you.

Comment: @David: The `GroupBy` in your answers makes it incorrect. It takes only a split-second to see that `GroupBy`. And to know that this `GroupBy` makes it incorrect requires experience with LINQ and some thinking about the problem. You may check my SO profile to see that I have that LINQ experience. And because I was writing my own answer, I already have thought about the problem. So, yes, you may apologize, although I am no god. Not everything you are not capable yourself - and this is no insult - means that it needs a god to do it. And finally: I didn't downvote your answer, just the other two.

Comment: @David: I hope this last comment also explains the perceived inconsistency in my comments. And I hope you understand that I am really trying to be constructive here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I have no doubt you are very experienced, but this is by no means, a good reason that you said you do not NEED read an answer before downvoting it. I might be incorrect in the answer, but I feel disgusted to those who are over confident, and find excuse saying I DISTRACTED his attention! You control yourself, I never force you to do so.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I found two trends in Stackoverflow, some one who downvote always, without even reading it; and some one alwasys upvote, also without reading it. I hope you are not the former, and you should not be,:), I hope I misunderstand you, if it is the case, please accept my apologies, if not, I would say, shame on those who do not think and downvote arbitrarily!

Comment: @David: Please read the comment again where I explain how I process answers like yours. Finally, for every downvote I leave a comment, so I can be addressed if the downvote really turns out to be unjustified or the answerer corrected the answer. And that's it for me with this discussion. You are insulting me all the time and I have had enough of it now.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, please tell me how I insulted you? I keep smiling, and you seem to be very nervous?

Comment: @David: In my book, being *disgusted* about someone is an insult. Calling someone *over confident* again and again is insulting as well.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, as I said, no sense to argue, I feel unhappy only when I saw you said I am distracting you, this is not my intention, and you seem to be very unhappy about my words? I just urge or suggest you, just be a little bit patient, did you follow my suggestion? Is it very harsh and extremely difficult to you?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, sorry about that. English is not my mother tongue, I sincerely apologize. what I mean is I dislike. Sorry again!

Comment: @David: Apology accepted. Still, this discussion is over now.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, also I said I dislike those who downvote arbitrarily, if you think you did have a careful thinking before you downvote, my words are not applicable to you, :) take it easy.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, good! Wish we both can learn sth from it. I shall arm myself with more LINQ and C# knowledge!

Comment: If there is an item < 10 and count < 3 it does not clear the sequence.  11 11 2 12 12 would be counted as a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most beautiful code, but it work.

Also it go over the input array only once

**Edit:** made some small changes in the code:

1. Add `itemInSequence` so can now change the sequence size
2. Remove the `if` check after the loop - no need for it

   ```
       var result = new List<List<int>>();
       int itemInSequence = 4;

       List<int> sequence = new List<int>();
       foreach (var item in arrInt)
       {
           if (item < 10)
           {
               sequence.Clear();
               continue;
           }

           sequence.Add(item);
           if (sequence.Count == itemInSequence)
           {
               result.Add(sequence.ToList());
               sequence = sequence.GetRange(1, itemInSequence - 1);
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: +1 The OP asked for sequences with "more than 3 items", so you might change `Count == 3` to `Count > 3`

Comment: @Andomar - thanks! I have update the code and make it little more generic and remove unneeded code

Comment: Nice.  I think it may not work now for sequences of length 5 or greater.

Comment: @Andomar - what happened in 5, I think this will work for any sequence length

Comment: Run your algorithm on `{ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1}` for example

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ seems forced here.  Here's a solution using `foreach`.  It visits each element only once.

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 11, 12, 13, 3, 5, 6, 11, 22, 12, 24, 5, 6, 22, 33 };

var cur = new List<int>();
var result = new List<List<int>>();
foreach (var ele in list)
{
    if (ele > 10)
        cur.Add(ele); // Add to current sequence
    else
    {
        if (cur.Count > 3)
            result.Add(cur); // Current sequence is valid
        cur = new List<int>(); // Start new sequence
    }
}
if (cur.Count > 3)
    result.Add(cur); // Final sequence is valid
```